# Recurrsive Tree total child count. This is not binary tree child PHP

Tags: php, c++, mysql, data-structures, tree

I 'm working on a project in which data is stored in recursive way form.
There makes a tree like this.
[image: Tree View]

I want to get total sub child count at each node.
I have root parent_id   123456.
I got direct child and there Id's by This code.

```
$parentcode = "Select ref_id from Total_childs where parent_id = '" . $exactcode . "'";
       $code2 = Run($parentcode);
       $data  = array();
       if (mysql_num_rows($code2) > 0) {
            while ($rowcont = mysql_fetch_object($code2)){
               $data[] = $rowcont->ref_id;
            }
        }
 data[0]

 data[1]

 data[2]

 data[3] shows direct child.
```

I want to get the total count of grand child at each node.?
This code sows the count of direct child.

```
  $qry_t_childs = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Total_childs where parent_id = '" . $exactcode . "' ";
       $qry_total_childs = Run($qry_t_childs);
       if (mysql_num_rows($qry_total_childs) > 0) {
        while ($rowfortotalchilds = mysql_fetch_array($qry_total_childs)) {

           $tot_childs_first = $rowfortotalchilds[0];
            $total_childs_first = $tot_childs_first;

        }
       }
```

This code would repeatedly But not working for more than one child in loop. Any possible way to get out of this? 
Here is my Table structure.

[image]

I implement this code within "Do-while" loop so this shows counting for 2nd level. But not for whole tree counting.?

Comment: Please include your table structure.

Comment: Please see my table structure

Comment: @shmosel Here is my all code structure . so.??